# Hyperbolic versus circular trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

The circular trig function can be used to solve triangles in the Euclidean plane. Can the hyperbolic trig functions be used in any similar way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines

Comment: @WillJagy I understand that hyperbolic trigonometry can be used in the hyperbolic plane. My questions is about their usefulness for surfaces with 0 curvature. Sine and cosine can be defined around the unit circle, and can be used to solve triangles in the plane. The hyperbolic counterparts can be defined around the unit hyperbola, but what can they solve in the plane?

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly mathematics, but hyperbolic functions enter into special relativity.

Suppose that an observer sees two objects moving away from him in the same direction, object 1 at speed $v_1$ and object 2 at a greater speed $v_2$.  If the speed of light is called $c$, then how fast (meaning relative speed $\Delta v$) does someone riding on object 1 see object 2 moving ahead of him?

In pre-relativistic mechanics, we would have simply

$\Delta v=v_2-v_1$.

But with the proper relativistic theory (in the absence of gravity, which is its own story) the relationship involves the hyperbolic tangent function:

$\Delta v/c=\tanh[\tanh^{-1}(v_2/c)-\tanh^{-1}(v_1/c)]$.

The hyperbolic tangent relation comes from the (Lorentz) transformation between spacetime reference frames being a modified form of a rotation.

Comment: Any tips on how to render tanh as a function like sin or cos?  I do not think the backslash works.  Thanks.

Comment: Hm backslash works for me, $ \$ $ \tanh x $ \$ $ = $\tanh x$

Comment: There you go! :)

Comment: You had everything right, there was just an extra dollar sign. If you click on "edited x mins ago" you can see the edit

Comment: Ik thanks, I'll try it bext time :-).